# React test if input accepts just number

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using react testing library to create my test.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Input = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(0);

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setState(e.target.value)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{state}</h1>
            <input placeholder='type' type="number" value={state} onChange={onChange}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Input;
```

My test:

```js
import Input from "./Input";
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'


describe('test if render', ()=> {
    test('check render text', ()=> {
        const { getByPlaceholderText, getByRole } = render(<Input />);
        const input = getByPlaceholderText('type');
        const h1 = getByRole('heading', {level: 1});
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "123" } });
        expect(h1).toHaveTextContent('123')
    });
    test('check not render text', ()=> {
        const { getByPlaceholderText, getByRole } = render(<Input />);
        const input = getByPlaceholderText('type');
        const h1 = getByRole('heading', {level: 1});
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "" } });
        expect(h1).toHaveTextContent('')
    })
});
```

The tests now are passed, but why? I just crated an input with type: number, not text, so i expect the test not to be passed? How to check an input with type number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the Web API. React works with Web API under the hood, and `react-testing-library` runs tests using the Web API.

`expect(h1).toHaveTextContent('123')` checks the `h1`'s `textContent` property, which is a `string`.

It's same for `input`'s `value` property. [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)'s `value` property is always a `string`. I'm not 100% sure why it's like that, but it makes sense to me that `HTMLInputElement.value` is always a `string` regardless of `type`.

```
    const onChange = (e) => {
        setState(e.target.value) // e.target.value is already a string. So, the state gets a string instead of a number here.
    };
```

If you really want a `number`, `HTMLInputElement` has another property called `valueAsNumber`, which is a number.

> `valueAsNumber`
>
> double: Returns the value of the element, interpreted as one of the following, in order:
>
> - A time value
> - A number
> - NaN if conversion is impossible

By the way, one of [the guiding principles of the Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles) is:

> It should be generally useful for testing the application components in the way the user would use it.

Users see numbers on a screen as texts and don't care their "type"s. So, it makes sense that we write tests based on texts that users see. For example, you may want to test if a number is beautifully formatted as well, like `1,234,567` instead of `1234567`, for some applications.